# Socket.io hides error information

Tags: javascript, debugging, console, socket.io

I am writing a multiplayer webgame using [socket](http://socket.io/).io and [phaser](http://phaser.io/) and am having some trouble debugging my application. The problem is that whenever a piece of javascript code crashes within a socket.io listener function, the program will crash silently and hide the error message from the console. For reference, I am talking about code in places like this:

```
var socket = io('http://localhost');
socket.on('news', function (data) {
  //Error ridden code
});
```

To clarify, it is not only socket.io related errors that are hidden, but *any* arbitrary error that occurs within one of those listeners (e.g a type error, accessing a property of undefined object etc.). This is problematic as a large bulk of the game's code occurs in response to socket messages from the server.

My question is - how do I get socket.io to stop censoring this information in the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the following code to perform error handling:

```
socket.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```